# What javascript mocking frameworks are people using?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocking, bdd

I'm using Jasmine for testing client & server side javascript and need to do some mocking. Has anyone got any suggestions for a good javascript mocking framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried this once, but ended up refactoring instead so it wasn't needed. It doesn't have dependencies, so it should work just fine on node.js. http://sinonjs.org/

These are testing frameworks, but some of them include mocking frameworks internally: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript

Comment: Sinon appears to be the only project that's still alive in 2014.

Answer (score 8):

I have not tried this one out(yet), but you could try [node-gently](https://github.com/felixge/node-gently) created by 
Felix Geisendörfer. Right now I saw [nodemock](https://github.com/arunoda/nodemock) update at search.npmjs.org which is commited frequently also.

Quick search gave me:

- https://github.com/aikar/mock
- https://github.com/arunoda/nodemock
- https://github.com/dhasenan/maryjane
- https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS
- https://github.com/dominictarr/remap

Answer (score 5):

I'm using node-gently and it works great. Is not as complete as sinon but feels more confortable to work with.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need a mocking framework? In *statically-typed* languages you need one because you can't change types at run-time.

I don't think you *need* this with JavaScript, the language is dynamic and powerful enough for you to not need this.

For example, I use `backbone` for my models and for the database connectivity. Backbone was designed well and has a single method `Backbone.Sync` that does all the database magic.

So I just do

```
var Backbone = require("backbone");
Backbone.Sync = function _mockedSync() {
  return ...;
}
```

You need to clarify exactly *what* you need. I don't think you *need* a mocking framework.

Comment: Mocking frameworks, broadly, do 3 major things: 'fake object' creation, method stubbing and verification of expectations. Duck punching does let you do simple stubbing easily, but doesn't help with the other functionality.

Comment: @ireddick you still have to do verification of expectations yourself, that's just duck typing and using `assert`. I call on YAGNI. Mocking when you have duck typing feels overengineered.

Comment: @Raynos as ireddick said, what you showed is just stubbing.  Check out this about the diff between mocks & stubs.  http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html  Some of the major missing pieces from duck punching is tracking that ONLY the interactions you want were called, and no others.  and how many times each interaction was called, and with which parameters.  yes you can build that yourself, but at that point you've just reinvented a mocking library.  And even if you're only stubbing, a mocking framework is arguably more concise & readable than duck punching

Comment: @JosephEames I argue otherwise, stubbing by monkey patching is more concise and readable then mocking frameworks

Comment: I've always hand rolled these mocks myself.