# How to test API connection library in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, testing, mocking, sinon

I'm writing an library for a third party rest API. I want to write a unit test so I can check if my library makes valid requests to that API without sending the request to the API. (I for example want to verify that the HMAC is correct in different scenarios).

I've been looking at [nock](http://npmjs.org/package/nock) and [sinon](http://npmjs.org/package/sinon).

While nock gives me the ability to create a fake server and fool my lib to connect to it, I can't find any way to handle and validate the request coming from my lib. It appears that sinon has the ability to create a fake server with your own functions handling the requests, but here I don't know how I can connect my lib to this fake server (it's using the core `https` module).

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to ensure that you call the right methods with the right arguments. This way you test the code you are responsible for, and no third party libraries (you don't need to test node core, node core tests node core). I'd investigate some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679914/what-javascript-mocking-frameworks-are-people-using).