# Automated testing node js and database

Tags: node.js, testing, continuous-integration

I'm using jenkins to automate the testing of my node js application? How do I test the queries to the database? How does Jenkins know to build the mongo db database first? How does automated testing work with database?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `Jenkins` for `CI`, I tend to use `TeamCity`, but I think your questions can be answered independently of which `CI technology` you use.

There is no definite answer to your questions, it all depends:

If you are looking to implement full `integration tests`, including querying a real database, then I would suggest creating a separate database just for testing like - `mydb-test`. You would have to configure your tests to use this database via config etc. In case you want to `isolate` your tests from the `data access layer`, then you need to mock the data access. This can be done by using a [mock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679914/what-javascript-mocking-frameworks-are-people-using), this will be easier to use depending on how well architected is your application code, where [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) IMHO is really important on this matter.